# Weird spacing issue?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a credit roll that starts from the bottom of the screen, moving all the way up until everything is out of frame without using any libraries, and right now, this is what it's looking like:

[image]

And there are two things that I dislike:

1. The space in between the role and the name is way too big. I haven't added any breaks for this to be happening, and I don't understand why that is.
2. The credit roll animation doesn't actually do anything at all. I think the issue lies within the CSS, but I'm not too sure.

Any help please?

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Pixelated;
  src: url(uni05_53.ttf);
}

h1 {
  font-family: Pixelated;
  color: white;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Pixelated;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.credits {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.credit {
  animation: creditRoll 15s linear forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes creditRoll {
  0% {
    top: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    top: -100%;
  }
}
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/3fz568hn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The spacing is caused by CSS's default `h` margin. Set your `h1` and `h3` to `margin: 0px` to remove it or overwrite as you need it to.
2. Solution for animation, when doing those move animation, you need to specifiy positions with `transform` property rather than normal top, left, etc

```
.credits {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: creditRoll 5s linear forwards;
}

   @keyframes creditRoll {
      0% {
        transform: translateY(100%);
      }
    
      50% {
        transform:translatey(0%);
      }
      100% {
        transform:translatey(-100%);
      }
   }
```

Comment: solution 1 worked (thanks), however changing it to credits also didn't work.

Comment: works really well except it doesn't go on once hitting the top of the screen, rather it just restarts, and i tried adding an overflow, but it's not working, here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/9rzywcf3/

Comment: Edited, this makes it go from bottom to top away out of the screen and stays like that without reseting. If you dont want it to leave the screen, remove the 100% breakpoint and replace the 50% one with value from 100%

Comment: Final issue, why does it slice off at the bottom?

Comment: Im not sure what do you mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250947/discussion-between-gamer-merch-and-dave111).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use headings, better to specify `div` tags with margin:

```js
let names = [
  "You",
  "DevBlizzard",
  "DevBlizzard",
  "DevBlizzard",
  "somebodysomeon2",
  "somebodysomeon2",
  "! kat.#8355",
  "fabianski987",
  'AWSQ - ca8 <a href="https://playcanvas.com/project/744016/overview/awsq">(Link)',
  'Uni 05_53 - Craig Kroeger'
];
let titles = [
  "Dedicated and Beloved Player:",
  "Mr. CEO:",
  "NOT a war criminal:",
  "Lead Programmer:",
  "Assistant Programmer (not really):",
  "Mr. Break-Your-Game:",
  "Graphic Designer/Artist:",
  "Composer/Sound Effect Designer:",
  "Original Creation:",
  "Font:"
];

let div = document.getElementById("credits")
for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
  let minidiv = document.createElement('div');
  minidiv.className = 'credit';
  let title = document.createElement('div');
  title.className = 'title';
  title.innerHTML = titles[i]; 
  minidiv.appendChild(title);
  let name = document.createElement('div');
  name.className = 'name';
  name.innerHTML = names[i];
  minidiv.appendChild(name);
  div.appendChild(minidiv);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/public-pixel');

#credits {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: creditRoll 15s linear forwards infinite;
}

#credits .title {
  font-family: 'Public Pixel', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

#credits .name {
  font-family: 'Public Pixel', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@keyframes creditRoll {
  0% {
    top: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    top: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/public-pixel" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="credits">
</div>
```

I don't have the `credits.js`, so this does not show the animation.